# Almacenar variable según búsqueda delimitada en C

Tags: c, busqueda

Partiendo de mi función:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

char extraer_info(const char* adaptador);

int leecad(char* cad, int n) {

    int i, c;
    c = getchar();
    if (c == EOF) {
        cad[0] = '\0';
        return 0;
    }

    if (c == '\n')
        i = 0;

    else {
        cad[0] = c;
        i = 1;
    }

    for (; i < n - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
        cad[i] = c;
    cad[i] = '\0';
    if (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

    return 1;

};

void main(void) {
    FILE* fp;
    char termAdaptador[BUFSIZ] = "Adaptador";
    char* p, * p2;
    char str[100], line[256], adaptador[100];

    // Redirection to ip.out.txt in order to gather the info I want
    strcpy(str, "> ip.out.txt ");
    strcat(str, "ipconfig /allcompartments /all");
    system(str);

    // Listing the adapters
    fp = fopen("ip.out.txt", "r");
    printf("\n    Los adaptadores de red disponibles son los siguientes:\n\n");
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
        if (strstr(line, termAdaptador) != NULL)
            printf(line);

    }

    // Scanf to choose my adapter and display its info
    printf("\n    Escribe el adaptador deseado: ");
    leecad(adaptador, 100);
    printf("\n    Has elegido %s. A continuacion tienes sus detalles:\n\n", adaptador);
    char adapt_info = extraer_info(adaptador);
}

char extraer_info(const char* adaptador)
{
    FILE* fp;
    const char* const Delim = "Adaptador"; // I want to find the string of letters that coincides with my variable "adaptador" to position my pointer there, don't know how to
    const char* terms[] = {
    "IPv4",
    "subred",
    "Puerta",
    "Servidores DNS",
    NULL
    };
    const char* termIp = "IPv4";

    fp = fopen("ip.out.txt", "r");
    char line[256];
    while (const char* begin = strstr(line, termIp)) {
        // Buscamos el último ':'
        begin = strrchr(begin, ':');
        begin += 2;

        // Buscamos el último dígito.
        const char* end = begin;
        while (isdigit(*end) || (*end == '.')) { ++end; }

        // Listo, entre begin y end.
        // Lo copiamos a una variable auxiliar.
        char datos[17];
        strncpy(datos, begin, (size_t)(end - begin));

        // Terminamos. La variable 'datos' contiene el texto.
        printf("%s", datos);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Accedo a un archivo redireccionado que contiene la información de mis adaptadores. ¿Cómo podría implementar delimitadores de manera que, en lugar de imprimirme la línea que responde a mis parámetros de búsqueda (los definidos en "terms"), almacenase el valor entre " : " y salto de línea? Por ejemplo, en cuanto a servidores DNS, estos pueden ocupar distintas líneas. ¿Cómo podría printarlos?

Es decir, dada la cadena de texto de mi archivo al que accedo:

```
   Direcci¢n IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.XX(Preferido)
```

El texto contenido entre " : " y el final de esta información. En el caso de DNS, de " : " al primer caracter no entero:

```
Servidores DNS. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 80.XX.XX.XXX
                                       80.XX.XX.YYY
   NetBIOS sobre TCP/IP. . . . . . . . . . . : ...
```

Comment: ¿Nos podrías poner datos de ejemplo con la entrada y salida esperada? Los ejemplos que has puesto no son nada claros y, sobre todo, no se sabe cómo quieres almacenar el resultado ni qué parte de la dirección IP.

Comment: La entrada sería un archivo redireccionado ".txt" con líneas de texto como las que he especificado en los dos últimos párrafos (los referentes a servidores DNS o IP). En cuanto a la salida, espero hacer un printf del tipo printf("IP: %s \n" variable1); printf("Mascara de subred: %s \n" variable2); etc..., no sé si es lo que preguntas. variable1, en este caso, haría referencia a la cadena de texto que hay entre " : " y el salto de línea en el ejemplo de más arriba, es decir, "192.168.1.XX(Preferido)". La opción de responder comentarios no es tan visual para el código..., gracias por atenderme.

Comment: Es que estos comentarios es para que [edites tu pregunta (pulsando aquí, por ejemplo)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/354845/edit) con la nueva información :) para que quede reflejada como mejora en la pregunta.

Comment: No lo había pensado! Lo tendré en cuenta para siguientes dudas (que no van a ser pocas). Gracias y disculpa las molestias.

Comment: Un placer, y las gracias a @Trauma, por su respuesta. Échale un vistazo y si tienes dudas déjale un comentario en su respuesta.

Comment: Si en cada línea del archivo lo tienes de esta forma: `Direcci¢n IPv4 : 192.168.1.XX(Preferido) `, te estás complicando. Si usas un formato de este tipo: `192.168.1.XX, myServerDNS, 232, ...`, sería mucha más sencillo leerlo, porque simplemente usamos la función `strtok` para poder obtener la cadena de forma separada y listo. Por eso, es recomendable usar un formato especifico para los datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta con usar adecuadamente algunas funciones:

- [`isdigit( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit): Para comprobar si un carácter es un dígito.
- [`strrchr( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr): Busca la última ocurrencia de un caracter.
- [`strncpy( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy): Copia de cadenas (añade un `\x00` al final).

A continuación, un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

const char line[] = "Direccion IPv4: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.99(Preferido)";

int main( void ) {
  const char* termIp = "IPv4";

  if( const char *begin = strstr( line, termIp ) ) {
    // Buscamos el último ':'
    begin = strrchr( begin, ':' );
    begin += 2;

    // Buscamos el último dígito.
    const char *end = begin;
    while( isdigit( *end ) || ( *end == '.' ) ) { ++end; }

    // Listo, entre begin y end.
    // Lo copiamos a una variable auxiliar.
    char datos[17];
    strncpy( datos, begin, (size_t)( end - begin ) );

    // Terminamos. La variable 'datos' contiene el texto.
    printf( "%s", datos );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Ya solo quedaría adaptarla al código original, cambiando el `if( )` por el `while( )`.

Comment: Gracias por tu celeridad, Trauma. Me asaltan dudas acerca de su sintaxis: a la hora de printar, ¿cómo llamo a la variable? Es decir, la cadena de caracteres contenida entre begin y end. Que, por cierto, ¿puede ser que la hayas formulado del revés? Siendo lo correcto " : " como inicio y el salto de línea como final, lo cual imagino que con cambiarlo rápidamente basta.

Comment: @Santos No estoy usando ninguna variable, lo saco por pantalla. Para guardarlo en una variable, puedes usar `sprintf( VARIABLE, ... )`, con los mismos argumentos que `printf( )`. Lo demás, no estoy seguro de entenderte. `end - begin` es para obtener el tamaño.

Comment: Disculpa nuevamente, @Trauma. He editado mi post inicial para ver si capto más o menos la estructura y sintaxis, implementando la función a mi código. Pongamos por ejemplo que quiero printar con sprintf la cadena relativa a esa primera búsqueda (la línea donde se encuentra el término "IPv4", habiendo extraído, según me comentas, únicamente la cadena entre los dos puntos y espacio y final de línea - no te había entendido al principio), ¿cómo debería formularlo?

Comment: @Santos A ver ahora.

Comment: Trauma, he editado nuevamente mi post inicial. No logro printar esa variable datos, ni con puts ni printf, no sé qué hago mal. Por otro lado, donde me dijiste str entiendo que es strstr, ¿no? Nuevamente, gracias por tu paciencia.

Comment: @Santos Editado. Aprovecho para mostrarte como se hace un [mcve], algo **muy útil** cuando formules tus preguntas.

Comment: Hago lo que me comentas pero sigue sin printarme la variable en cuestión. He editado nuevamente mi post inicial, con el código entero por si ayuda a identificar el error, pero realmente la parte que atañe es la final (en la que he implementado tu ayuda). Sinceramente, no entiendo cómo no funciona: he revisado el .txt en cuestión y, evidentemente, sigue contando con la palabra clave y todo. En cuanto al enlace, lo tendré en cuenta para siguientes preguntas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107913/discussion-between-santos-and-trauma).